# Browse my tables?

Tags: azure-data-lake

I have an Azure Data Lake instance. It has tables in it. The tables have data in them. I simply want to **look at the data in the tables, interactively,** without having to run an Azure Data Lake batch job and turn them into CSV or TSV files.

This seems like an ordinary request but I can't figure out how to do it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing U-SQL tables is not currently supported.  If you go via the Azure Portal, you can use Data Explorer which makes scripting the job easy, via its 'Query Table' option, or just script it yourself.

If you genuinely feel this is missing, create a feedback item and vote for it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake).

Comment: Here's a similar request on UserVoice here:  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/10433910-preview-the-contents-of-a-u-sql-table-without-havi